# Replacing first character in file Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I'm trying to replace the first character in a file so that I end up with either a `1` or a `0` in it. Here's my code:

```
import os

hostName = raw_input("IP: ")
communicate = open("communicate.txt", "w")

while True:
    response = os.system("ping " + hostName + " -c 1")
    if response == 0:
        # Replace first character with '1'
    else:
        # Replace first character with '0'
```

I am running the code in a Linux virtual machine through the terminal.

Comment: Once you open the file with `"w"`, it's already overwritten.

Comment: Is the `communicate.txt` file empty? If not, do you want to preserve it's contents (except first character)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to do what you want:

```
import os
import time

hostName = raw_input("IP: ")
communicateFd = os.open("communicate.txt", os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR)
communicate = os.fdopen(communicateFd, 'r+b')

while True:
    communicate.seek(0)
    response = os.system("ping " + hostName + " -c 1")
    if response == 0:
        communicate.write('1')
    else:
        communicate.write('0')
    time.sleep(1)

communicate.close()
```

As noted by others, opening with mode `'w'` will truncate the file, destroying the previous contents, if any.

Using the `os` module, we can have a bit more control over how the file is opened.  In this case, it's created only if it doesn't exist, and then opened in read/write mode.

At the top of the loop we `seek` to the beginning of the file, allowing us to simply rewrite the first byte as many times as necessary.

A sleep statement was added to keep this from being a tight loop, but it can be removed without affecting the file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

hostName = raw_input("IP: ")
communicate = open("communicate.txt", "r+")
while True:
    response = os.system("ping " + hostName + " -c 1")
    if response == 0:
        text = communicate.read()
        communicate.write(str(1) + text[1:])
    else:
        text = communicate.read()
        communicate.write(str(0) + text[1:])
 communicate.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to preserve the contents of the file, and replace the first character,
you can simply `read` the file, save its contents (excluding the 1st character) in a variable,
 and then `write` it in an overwritten file, as such:

```
import os

hostName = raw_input("IP: ")

with open("communicate.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()[1:]

while True:
    response = os.system("ping " + hostName + " -c 1")
    if response == 0:
        with open("communicate.txt", "w") as communicate:
            comunicate.write('1' + content)
    else:
        with open("communicate.txt", "w") as communicate:
            comunicate.write('0' + content)
```

If you want to keep on replacing the 1st character,
then you need to override your file continuesly.
I would suggest if this is some checkup, let the code sleep for a few seconds on every iteration of your `while` loop, using the `sleep` function from the `time` module
I hope I helped!